# In python, when self can be omitted?

Tags: python, class

Codes below defined *Duck* class as composited from *Bill* class and *Tail* class. My questions is that as for the method *about()* inside *Duck* class definition, why can one write `bill.description` and `tail.length`? Is `self` omitted here? If yes, when can I omit `self`? Can I omit them inside `__init__` method?

```
class Bill(): 
    def __init__(self, description):
        self.description = description 
class Tail(): 
    def __init__(self, length): 
        self.length = length 
class Duck(): 
    def __init__(self, bill, tail): 
        self.bill = bill
        self.tail = tail 
    def about(self): 
        print('This duck has a', bill.description, 'bill and a', tail.length, 'tail')
tail = Tail('long')
bill = Bill('wide orange') 
duck = Duck(bill, tail)
duck.about()
```

The output are as follows,
[image]

Comment: It actually uses names `tail` and `bill` from global scope. Try changing creation to `tail1 = Tail('long')` - NameError will be raised.

Comment: Why do you want to omit self? Its Python language specific construct used in objects to refer to themselves. If you dont use it, you are referring to global context.

Comment: @WaxCage Because I know that if I wrote self.bill.description and self.tail.length in about() method, my code would work, too. But I was surprised to see that I could even omit self!

Comment: I hope you already understood, that self CANNOT be omitted! Calling variable with and without self have different meaning and refers to different values. If you didn't understand from already given answers, i can explain in detail. Do you know OOP well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make a long story short: you *MUST* use `self.` whenever you want to access an attribute (data attribute, property or method) of the current instance.

For a somewhat more detailed answer: when using `def` in a `class` statement, what you create is not a "method" but a plain function. When looked up a class or instance attribute (`Duck.about` or `duck.about`) this function will be wrapped (together with the class and instance on which it's looked up) in a callable `method` object that will take care of automagically inject the instance (or class) object as first parameter to the function call. You can read the whole details here :  https://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod

As other already mentionned, your code snippet only accidentally "works" because it ends up looking global names that happens to be defined, and breaks as soon as these names are not defined:

```
# tail = Tail('long')
# bill = Bill('wide orange') 
duck = Duck(Bill('wide orange'), Tail('long'))
duck.about()
```

=> crashes with a `NameError`

You'd also get unexpected results if rebinding these global names ie:

```
tail = Tail('long')
bill = Bill('wide orange') 
duck1 = Duck(bill, tail)

tail = Tail('short')
bill = Bill('norvegian blue') 
duck2 = Duck(bill, tail)

duck1.about()
```

=> Duh, why does it prints "short norvegian blue" ???

Comment: Because global variable bill is now tagged at object Bill('norvegian blue'). One more question, is the rule of namespace inside a class definition the same as that inside a function definition? For instance, if I define a variable inside a class, then it is recognized as local?

Comment: the `class` statement defines a namespace but this namespace only lives until the `class` statement is executed (which is as soon as the code exists the `class` statement's block) so functions defined inside the `class` cannot directly access other names defined within the `class` statement block. But since names defined in this namespace become attributes of the class (unless some custom metaclass remove them from the attributes dict) these names can be accessed thru `self.__class__.<somename>` or (if no instance attribute shadows them) directly as `self.<somename>. This is all documented...

Answer (score 4):

In Python explicit is better than implicit and `self` cannot ever be omitted when accessing member variables.

In your case you actually use names from global scope. To trigger an error simply assign the created objects to other names:

```
tail1 = Tail('long')
bill1 = Bill('another')
duck = Duck(tail1, bill1)
duck.about()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write that because you have defined a global variable `bill` and `tail`, which is being referenced here.

```
...
    def about(self): 
        print('This duck has a', bill.description, 'bill and a', tail.length, 'tail')
                         # these ^^^^                            ^^^^

# refer to these vvvv
tail = Tail('long')
bill = Bill('wide orange')
```

So it's not doing what you think. If you want to refer to the `bill` and `tail` properties of your current object, you **cannot** omit `self`, it has to be `self.bill` and `self.tail`. Your code will break if you rename or remove those global variables.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid doing that. `bill` in `about()` will refer to `bill` in the outer scope, in this case the global one. So when you change the value of that global variable, the output of `about()` is also affected:

```
>>> tail = Tail('long')
>>> bill = Bill('wide orange')
>>> duck = Duck(bill, tail)
>>> duck.about()
This duck has a wide orange bill and a long tail
>>> bill = Bill('DIFFERENT')
>>> duck.about()
This duck has a DIFFERENT bill and a long tail
```

In order to reference the `bill` and `tail` objects that were passed to `Duck()` and are stored within the instance, you always need to use `self.bill` and `self.tail`.