# "self" in a class method

Tags: python, class, methods, self

I am defining a method within a class which creates a dictionary. This dictionary simply gives each letter of the alphabet a value. So the method doesn't manipulate any instances of that class. Do I need to have `self` as a parameter of the method in this case?

```
def build_shift_dict(self, shift):
    import string
    low = string.ascii_lowercase*2
    up = string.ascii_uppercase*2
    punc = list(" !@#$%^&*()-_+={}[]|\:;'<>?,./\"")
    shift_dict = {}

    for i in low[:26]:
        shift_dict[i] = low[low.index(i) + shift]

    for i in up[:26]:
        shift_dict[i] = up[up.index(i) + shift]

    for i in punc:
        shift_dict[i] = i

    return shift_dict
```

Comment: Yes, if it is an instance method you need the `self` parameter because python will pass it in. Whether if *should* be an instance method is a different question.

Comment: I'll leave it for someone else to decide but I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554738/python-self-no-self-and-cls and maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37963018/in-python-when-self-can-be-omitted are probably duplicates

Comment: Still not fully clear why "self" is needed in a method which not using the instance of the class, but I guess i need to take it as a given and apply @staticmethod instead

Comment: @Mikki because the instance will automatically be assigned to the first argument of the function. If you leave out `self` and write `def build_shift_dict(shift):` then you won't have got a shift, but the instance will be called `shift`. The word `self` doesn't have any magical properties - it's just the number of arguments that's important.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can just make it a [static method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod)

```
@staticmethod
def build_shift_dict(shift):
    ... do the things
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to have a function that doesn't belong either to the Class' instance or to the class you can use `@staticmethod` decorator to the function, note that you need to remove `self` hence:

```
@staticmethod
def build_shift_dict(shift):
    import string
    low = string.ascii_lowercase*2
    up = string.ascii_uppercase*2
    punc = list(" !@#$%^&*()-_+={}[]|\:;'<>?,./\"")
    shift_dict = {}
    
    for i in low[:26]:   
            shift_dict[i] = low[low.index(i) + shift]
            
    for i in up[:26]:   
            shift_dict[i] = up[up.index(i) + shift]
            
    for i in punc:   
            shift_dict[i] = i
    
    return shift_dict
```

---

### Documentation

- [realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/](https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/)

### Other Stack Overflow Answers

- [python-self-no-self-and-cls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554738/python-self-no-self-and-cls)
- [python-when-self-can-be-omitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37963018/in-python-when-self-can-be-omitted)

### Observations

For some, is considerated a good programming design to user staticmethods (or at least not all the time) and is normally better view the function to be declared outside of the class rather then use it within and then wrap it in a staticmethod, but really depends.

Also, declare a staticmethod or make a function **outside a class** is basically the same thing, hence is more a **design choice rather than a functionality choice** and is up to the designer / developer to choose which one is the best.